# Three JS rotate model towards xyz position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to rotate an object in Three JS towards a fixed xyz location within a space. Currently I'm able to achieve it like this:

```
var position_x  = -0.85;
var position_z  = -4.44;

model.lookAt(position_x, 0, position_z);
```

However the lookAt() function rotates the model instantly and I would like to rotate the model more slowly. Is there a way to accomplish this using built in Three JS functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to accomplish this using built in Three JS functions?

Yes, you can use [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=quater#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards) which works similar to Unity's `Quaternion.rotateTowards()` method.

The idea is to compute a target orientation which is represented by a quaternion. You can do this by using `Matrix4.lookAt()` and then create a quaternion based on this matrix via `Quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix()`.

Next, you compute an angular step per frame the will define how much your object is turned towards the target. The computation of `step` looks like so:

```js
const step = speed * delta;
```

`delta` is the time delta value in seconds and `speed` represents the turn rate of our model in radians per second.

A complete code example is available is here:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_math_orientation_transform

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly! :)